# Database performance comparison

Tags: windows-phone-7

Im asking for a performance comparisons of the databases available for WP7. I'm especially interested in a comparison of [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com) and [SQLite](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you can find a direct comparison as they are different types of database. SQLite is an RDBMS, while terling is an object (or document) database.

They are designed to work in different ways and serve different purposes.

The one which is more appropriate to you will likely not be based solely on performance.

**Update**
As an RDBMS, SQLite is better suited to entities which have a relationship and or would be better off being stored in a normalised form.
SQLite is cross platform and will allow you to work on multiple platforms more easily.
Sterling is specifically designed to work in Silverlight/IsolatedStorage.

Comment: to me it seems that Sterling, even though being an OO database, tries to fulfill the same purpose as SQLite, or what did you mean by "they serve different purposes"?